# Mostrar contador de notificaciones en BottomNavigation

Tags: android

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Actualmente lo tengo como la segunda imagen, pero me ha parecido un poco mas atractivo con el **navigation bottom**, pero quiero saber como puedo hacer que aparezca el globito rojo con el numero de notificaciones(contador). El globo rojo es un `"Drawable"`

Answer (score 2):

Te recomiendo utilizar esta libreria:

https://github.com/aurelhubert/ahbottomnavigation

Consiste en un BottomNavigation mas avanzado que el original, se adapta mucho mas fácil a tus necesidades, por ejemplo, así es como puedes poner un "badge" de notificación:

```
 bottomNavigation.setNotification(notification, bottomNavigation.getItemsCount() - 4);
```

y este seria el resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ya lo he descargo del sitio, despues de eso que hago?

Comment: Si agregas un link debes agregar de preferencia lo más relevante de su contenido. ¿ Ahora como implementa el OP esta library?